# Cannot find -llintl in GTK+

Tags: c++, c, gtk, codeblocks, gtk3

Iv'e tried to add gtk+ in Code:Blocks. However, when I tried to run and to compile the code (That Iv'e code from the Code:Blocks) I got an error `cannot find -lintl | error: ld returned 1 exit status`

How can I make -lintl found? How can I add it to my project\ to my computer?

**EDIT**: This is the build log I have got:

```
Checking for existence: C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.exe

-------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include  -c C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.c -o C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.o
C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.c:34:3: warning: 'gtk_vbox_new' is deprecated: Use 'gtk_box_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   vbox = gtk_vbox_new (TRUE, 6);
   ^
In file included from C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:245:0,
                 from C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.c:2:
C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h:60:13: note: declared here
 GtkWidget * gtk_vbox_new      (gboolean homogeneous,
             ^
mingw32-g++.exe  -o C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.exe C:\Users\magshimim\Documents\Test\main.o  -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl   
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lintl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it from the command line?

Comment: @ErikW I tried to compile it with gcc and I've got the same error

Comment: Your code is not relevant to why the linker cannot find a library.
Replace it with the build log of the failing build, which you
will find in Code::Blocks in the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab).

Comment: I see you're on Windows. On Windows, `libintl` is a library that you will have to install separately
from your toolchain, in the manner appropriate to your development
environment (e.g. native Windows, MSYS2, Cygwin...), which we don't
know. Google e.g. "libintl for Windows", "libintl for MSYS2" ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is implemented in Windows, but in linux, there is no such library (at least not literally `libintl.so`). There is a `libintl.h` though, so I suspect there is no actual code for `libintl` - just definitions (macros).

So I'd suggest you try to compile without the `-lintl` in the command line.

You could check on your disk if a library `libintl`(.dll?) exists in the library dirs of the minggw package, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully aware what is exactly behind libintl but I've seen it installed when installing gettext (https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/). The file libintl.so is mentioned in the documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).